# Get all records for Top N Distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `BookAuthor` table like below (SQL Server 2008 R2 Ent):

```
BookID  AuthorID
------  --------
43      676
43      76
43      354
71      89
71      76
99      71
64      50
64      39
64      354
```

I want to get all records for top 2 distinct BookID. So, expected output will be as below:

```
    BookID  AuthorID
    ------  --------
    43      676
    43      76
    43      354
    71      89
    71      76
```

I tried the below simplest query and it is only returning 2 rows.

```
Select top 2 * from BookAuthor order by BookID ASC
```

So, how can I proceed here ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your desired result does not match if you were ordering by BookID ascending. How do you want to decide Top 2?

Comment: I want to get the results for top 2 distinct bookIDs. That is all the rows where bookID in (43,71).

Comment: In absence of a sort the return order is not guaranteed.  Even if the table has a clustered index there is no guarantee the rows would be returned in that order.  If you want that row order then add a column rowNumber that is the desired order and sort on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following to get the `TOP 2 DISTINCT` BookIds:

```
select t1.bookid, t1.authorid
from BookAuthor t1
inner join
(
  select distinct top 2 bookid
  from BookAuthor
  order by bookid
) t2
  on t1.bookid = t2.bookid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fc4e/1)

You stated that you want the Books with the id's 43, 71 returned because those are the top 2 book ids but data in a table is not inherently ordered. Unless you have another column that you can get the rows in that order, if you order by bookid ascending then you will return 43, 64.

Answer (score 0):

What about below query:

```
Select * from BookAuthor where BookID in(
select Distinct top 2 BookID from BookAuthor order by BookID asc)
```

It's working fine for me

Comment: I'm not surprised. Its essentially the same query as given in bluefeet's answer except that you have moved the restriction from the join to the where clause.